# Reformatting a Data Frame with Unaligned Data and Gaps

Tags: r

I have a dataset coming in that has a strange report format and I need to get it into a workable dataframe. The data I'm working with looks like this:

```
ids<-(c("A101","","","","B101","","","C101","","",""))
dx<-c("Lung","","","","Kidney","","","Prostate","","","")
alt<-c("","A766","G283","F933","","B293","T432","","U920","D289","S203")
val<-c(NA,3.2,4.3,7.2,NA,2.1,3.8,NA,8.1,5.3,7.1)
df.in<-data.frame(ids,dx,alt,val)
```

which generates a format that has a series of unaligned data to the sample id. I would like them to align in such a way that the final data frame would look like this:

```
ids<-(c("A101","A101","A101","B101","B101","C101","C101","C101"))
dx<-c("Lung","Lung","Lung","Kidney","Kidney","Prostate","Prostate","Prostate")
alt<-c("A766","G283","F933","B293","T432","U920","D289","S203")
val<-c(3.2,4.3,7.2,2.1,3.8,8.1,5.3,7.1)
df.out<-data.frame(ids,dx,alt,val)
```

I explored different approaches using plyr, lapply but can't seem to get these look like the 'df.out' data format above. Note that there is no symmetry to the number of values a sample might have (ie, some might just have 1 value where others might have up to 10). Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Replace blank cells "" with NA
df.in[df.in == ""] <- NA

# Fill NA values with value of row above it
df.in %>% 
  fill(c(ids, dx), .direction = "down") %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) # optional

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  ids   dx       alt     val
  <chr> <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 A101  Lung     A766   3.20
2 A101  Lung     G283   4.30
3 A101  Lung     F933   7.20
4 B101  Kidney   B293   2.10
5 B101  Kidney   T432   3.80
6 C101  Prostate U920   8.10
7 C101  Prostate D289   5.30
8 C101  Prostate S203   7.10
```

The last line in the chain, `mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)` is optional and converts factors to character. We can avoid this step by using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the datasets.

Comment: This works quite well. Thanks. I do get an error for the mutate_if function as it appears not be be available in my install (R version 3.4, tidyr_0.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
> indx=rep(which(is.na(df.in$val)),rle(cumsum(is.na(df.in$val)))$length)
> na.omit(cbind(df.in[indx,-4],val=df.in$val))
     ids       dx alt val
1.1 A101     Lung     3.2
1.2 A101     Lung     4.3
1.3 A101     Lung     7.2
5.1 B101   Kidney     2.1
5.2 B101   Kidney     3.8
8.1 C101 Prostate     8.1
8.2 C101 Prostate     5.3
8.3 C101 Prostate     7.1
```

Breakdown:

```
> first<-which(is.na(df.in$val))# The positions for every new group ie 1,5 and 8
> groups=cumsum(is.na(df.in$val))#The groups you have
> groupsize=rle(groups)$length#The size of the groups
> newdf=transform(df.in[rep(first,groupsize),],val=df.in$val)#Create the new df
> newdf=na.omit(newdf)#Remove the NA rows
> row.names(newdf)=NULL# REMOVE THE ROWNAMES GIVEN
> newdf
   ids       dx alt val
1 A101     Lung     3.2
2 A101     Lung     4.3
3 A101     Lung     7.2
4 B101   Kidney     2.1
5 B101   Kidney     3.8
6 C101 Prostate     8.1
7 C101 Prostate     5.3
8 C101 Prostate     7.1
```